# Vue.js calling the same method from different inputs on @change listener yields duplicate values in API fetch url /categories variables

Tags: api, vue.js, url, input, methods

Attempting to change the API fetch url depending on two different inputs. The first select input chooses the restaurant. The second input radio button group chooses the category.
Calling the same method @change from either type of input and that duplicates the value. I'm wondering if I can be more specific to each input listener to get the distinct values into both variables?

This is a well-formed url:

```
http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/123456/Category1

http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/{restaurantNumber}/{categoryNumber}
```

This is what I currently get (poorly formed/duplicated values):

```
http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/Category1/Category1
```

Or:

```
http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/123456/123456
```

[image]

Would I need to create separate methods, then send the selected value to the `fetchProducts` method? Or change the  `= event.target.value;` binding to be more specific to each type of input?

Get all restaurant data sample:

[image]

Product data sample:

[image]

Full page below, `fetchProducts` is where my code is incorrect:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }

    [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
    }

    .upper-first-letter::first-letter {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .dollar-sign::before {
        content: "$";
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <!--SELECT RESTAURANT-->
        <div class="card mt-5 shadow-sm">
            <h1 class="card-header">Select Restaurant</h1>
            <select v-model="selectedRest" @change="fetchProducts" class="custom-select custom-select-lg d-inline-block m-3 w-25">
                <option disabled value="">Please select a restaurant</option>
                <option v-for="s in restNums" :value="s.RestaurantNumber">{{s.RestaurantName}}</option>
            </select>
            <p class="lead ml-4 text-secondary">Selected Restaurant Number: <strong>{{ selectedRest }}</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card mt-5 shadow-sm">
            <h1 class="card-header">Menu Board</h1>
            <!--SELECT CATEGORY-->
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="subsCat" value="Category1" v-model="pickedCat" @change="fetchProducts">
                <label for="subsCat">Subs</label>
                <input type="radio" id="nonSubsCat" value="Category2" v-model="pickedCat" @change="fetchProducts">
                <label for="nonSubsCat">Non Subs</label>
                <p class="lead ml-4 text-secondary">Picked: {{ pickedCat }}</p>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item:</th>
                        <th>Six Inch Price:</th>
                        <th>Foot Long Price:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody v-cloak>
                    <tr v-for="p in products">
                        <td>{{p.Name}}</td>
                        <td class="dollar-sign">{{p.SixInchPrice}}</td>
                        <td class="dollar-sign">{{p.FootLongPrice}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        restNums: [],
        selectedRest: '',
        pickedCat: '',
        products: []

    },
    created: function() {
        this.fetchRestaurants();
        //this.fetchProducts();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchRestaurants: function() {
            const urlRestaurants = 'http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/getallrestaurants';

            axios.get(urlRestaurants)
                .then(function(resRestaurants) {
                    vm.restNums = resRestaurants.data.slice(0, 10);
            })
        },

        fetchProducts: function(event) {
            //BOTH VARIABLES GET THE LAST CHOSEN VALUE FROM
            //EITHER OF THE INPUTS (SELECT DROP DOWN OR RADIO BUTTONS)
            //CAN event.target.value BE MORE SPECIFIC TO EACH TYPE OF INPUT
            //CURRENTLY AMBIGUOS AND DUPLICATING VALUE TO BOTH var
            var restNum = event.target.value;
            var categoryNum = event.target.value;
    
            var urlProducts = 'http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/' + restNum + '/' + categoryNum;
            
            //FORMAT
            //var urlProducts =     http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/{restaurantNumber}/{categoryNumber}
            
            //HARDCODED FULL LENGTH EXAMPLES
            // var urlProducts = http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/123456/Category1
            // var urlProducts = http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/123456/Category2
            // var urlProducts = http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/789000/Category2
            // var urlProducts = http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/789000/Category2

            axios.get(urlProducts)
                .then(function(resProducts) {
                    vm.products = resProducts.data.productViewModels.slice(0, 10);
            })
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using `v-model` in the select and input fields. So, in the `fetchProducts` method, simply use them instead of getting value from the event.

```
fetchProducts: function(event) {    
            var urlProducts = 'http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/' + this.selectedRest + '/' + this.pickedCat;

            axios.get(urlProducts)
                .then(function(resProducts) {
                    vm.products = resProducts.data.productViewModels.slice(0, 10);
            })
        }
```

Comment: Nice! I was wondering how I can get that v-model data value to where I need it. Also this achieves some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps you:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <!--SELECT RESTAURANT-->
      <div class="card mt-5 shadow-sm">
        <h1 class="card-header">Select Restaurant</h1>
        <select
          v-model="selectedRest"
          @change="fetchProducts(selectedRest)"
          class="custom-select custom-select-lg d-inline-block m-3 w-25"
        >
          <option disabled value="">Please select a restaurant</option>
          <option v-for="s in restNums" :value="s.RestaurantNumber">
            {{ s.RestaurantName }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <p class="lead ml-4 text-secondary">
          Selected Restaurant Number: <strong>{{ selectedRest }}</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card mt-5 shadow-sm">
        <h1 class="card-header">Menu Board</h1>
        <!--SELECT CATEGORY-->
        <div>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="subsCat"
            value="Category1"
            v-model="pickedCat"
            @change="fetchProducts(selectedRest)"
          />
          <label for="subsCat">Subs</label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="nonSubsCat"
            value="Category2"
            v-model="pickedCat"
            @change="fetchProducts(selectedRest)"
          />
          <label for="nonSubsCat">Non Subs</label>
          <p class="lead ml-4 text-secondary">Picked: {{ pickedCat }}</p>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Item:</th>
              <th>Six Inch Price:</th>
              <th>Foot Long Price:</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody v-cloak>
            <tr v-for="p in products">
              <td>{{ p.Name }}</td>
              <td class="dollar-sign">{{ p.SixInchPrice }}</td>
              <td class="dollar-sign">{{ p.FootLongPrice }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Show URL now: {{ apiUrl }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      restNums: [],
      selectedRest: "",
      pickedCat: "",
      products: [],
      apiUrl: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchRestaurants().then((data) => {
      this.restNums = data;
    });
    //this.fetchProducts();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchRestaurants: function () {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const mockData = [
            {
              RestaurantId: 6969,
              RestaurantNumber: "12345",
              RestaurantName: "Test Res",
              updatedBy: "dev",
            },
            {
              RestaurantId: 666,
              RestaurantNumber: "999",
              RestaurantName: "Test Res2",
              updatedBy: "suba",
            },
          ];
          resolve(mockData);
        }, 500);
      });
    },

    fetchProducts: function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      this.apiUrl = `http://dummyendpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/products/${event}/${this.pickedCat}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

a playable example can be found here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-forest-24p0v?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Yeah, that does help a lot. Excellent demo example but I'm a bit beyond my Vue skill level. Can I ask: When the data() is pushed into a return, does that make it accessible to the other methods more so?

Comment: @Kerry777, its just the common way to handle `data` inside a component.
The different between your code and mine is just that i use Single File Components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

there for my components `data` needs to be a function that returns a object.